# Datagridview converting Datetime to String

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, typeconverter

How to convert datagridview item (datetime format) to string.

This is my code:

```
ComboBox1.Text = DatagridView1.Item(4, 1).Value.ToString()
```

Can someone help me? This is the full code:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick

    btnEdit.Visible = True
    Dim i As Integer
    i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
    Dim x As String = CStr(DataGridView1.Item(4, i).Value.ToString)
    Dim y As String = CStr(DataGridView1.Item(5, i).Value.ToString)

    MsgBox(x)
    MsgBox(y)

    txtTrainID.Text = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value
    txtRouteID.Text = DataGridView1.Item(1, i).Value
    txtLine.Text = DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value
    cmbLine1.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value
    cmbLine2.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value
    cmbLine3.Text = DataGridView1.Item(3, i).Value
    cmbTS.Text = x.ToString
    cmbTA.Text = y.ToString
    txtTrainName.Text = DataGridView1.Item(6, i).Value
    cmbFlag.Text = DataGridView1.Item(7, i).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: it doesent return string value . I need to convert the datetime value from my gridview . and put it on my combobox as string .

Comment: It generates an error? What it returns then?

Comment: it is not transferring in the combobox.text . i mean the item on the gridview as datetime . is not showing in the combobox.text .

Comment: Are you sure the cell you are getting is not empty? Are you sure the line of code is executing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the `Value` to `ComboBox` the property must set as `DropDownStyle = DropDown` and you don't need this `i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index` to get the `currentRowIndex` of the `DataGridView` in `CellClick event`

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick 

   ComboBox1.Text = DatagridView1.Item(4, e.RowIndex).Value.ToString()

End Sub
```